# WPF word-wrapping: Missing words when using custom font

Tags: c#, wpf, word-wrap, custom-font

I'm using a custom font known as [Pigiarniq](http://www.tiro.com/syllabics/resources/index.html) in a WPF application.  I have found that from time to time, words will disappear from TextBlocks that use this font.  The words that disappear would have appeared at the end of the line they are on, or perhaps on the next line, which makes me think that something is wrong with the Text wrapping.  I have finally (after much difficulty) isolated the problem to a small piece of code (NOTE: this is only a test to confirm the problem occurs. This is not part of my program):

```
<Window x:Class="Test_the_textbox_width.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="850">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Name="textBlock1"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontFamily="Pigiarniq%20Regular.ttf#Pigiarniq"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               FontSize="15"
               Margin="10">
        <TextBlock.Text>
             You do not need to enter both manually. Rates are calculated using true depositional 
            (uncompacted) thicknesses, rather than measured present-day thicknesses.
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The word "thicknesses" that occurs after "(uncompacted)" does not appear.  If I resize the window manually using the window handle, it will re-appear.

NOTE: I have put the TextBlock in a Grid element above because sometimes this problem occurs when the TextBlock is in a Grid.  In another instance it was inside an InlineUIContainer.  There were other instances as well.

I have found that this behaviour doesn't occur if I set the width explicitly, such as if I subscribe to the Loaded event on the TextBlock:

```
private void textBlock1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Width = textBlock1.ActualWidth;
        //textBlock1.Width = Double.NaN;  //if you leave this in, you get the bad behaviour
    }
```

Very strange!  Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?  My boss would really like to use this font, so it's not like I can just choose another font (I've never seen this happen with any other font).  I'm also not too keen on the idea of watching every change in the layout and re-sizing every textblock appropriately that uses Pigiarniq.

Comment: why do you want to `textBlock1.Width = Double.NaN;` in `TextBox.Loaded` eventhandler?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the font itself. Try any other font, play around with `Width="850"` and I'm sure you will find values that hide text from other fonts too. Your composition is a little unclear. Why do you put the Textblock within another Grid? I guess this textblock in grid in grid messes up things a little. Also, leave that Loaded event out. Can't see why this should be there.

Comment: @publicgk: I don't.  I was proving that if you switch the width of the TextBlock back to Auto (which is equivalent to setting it to NaN), the bad behavior returns.

Comment: @Markus: I have tried to replicate this behavior a little with several other fonts (with the text in the textblock above)- I have not had success.  If anyone out there finds an example of this happening in another font, let me know.  It seems to be very context specific.  About the composition: I was trying to replicate the behavior that occurred in my program, so I wouldn't have to post a large code base on SO.  The Textblocks that have this problem are sometimes found in Grids.  About the loaded event: I don't want the loaded event.  But without it, the problem occurs.

Comment: @skybluecodeflier try inspecting the textblock with Snoop and see if it got valid values for DesiredSize and ActualSize (also inspect if the textbox in Snoop shows up correct). I really think this is more a problem that the grid clips the textblock and has nothing to do with the textblock.

Comment: @skybluecodeflier, do you face the same problem if you set the width of TextBlock to Auto **via XAML** (i.e. <TextBlock Width=Auto ... />) and **not** via the Loaded event handler. I believe the root cause of the problem is that you are trying to set the width of a control after system has calculated the actualwidth but before it renders the textblock. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx), _The Loaded event is raised before the final rendering, but after the layout system has calculated all necessary values for rendering._

Comment: @Markus: I took a look with Snoop.  The Desired width turns out to be larger than the actual width by about 20 dip's (device indep. pixels) but that seems more or less constant whether the problem is occurring or not.  I'm not sure what that means, though- why is the TextBlock not getting the width it wants all the time?  Also, I'm not sure what you meant by the TextBlock showing up correctly in Snoop- the properties look fine and it looks exactly the same in the Magnify window.  I also tried removing BOTH Grids that the TextBlock was inside of- didn't help.

Comment: @publicgk: Yep, the problem remains.  I actually added the Loaded event handler AFTER I discovered the problem. I was mainly trying to see if fixing the width of the textblock to a value would fix the problem.  The Loaded handler proved that it will fix the problem.  So I decided to see if fixing the width and then changing it back to Auto cause the problem again.  If it didn't cause the problem, then the initial rendering would be suspect.  But it DID still cause the problem, so I don't know what's wrong.  Did that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

We actually encountered the same problem with the default system font.
This seems to be a bug in the textblock line break feature itself.

We found that in windows with fixed size, the line break **sometimes** ignores the last word.
This happened for various sizes and sentences.

We couldn't find a real solution, so our workaround was to manually include the line breaks in the text.

We also did quite a bit of googling on the subject because i refused to believe that such an issue was undocumented..but it seems this is undocumented (or at least hard to find as of two months ago) and after some very rigorous testing i am convinced that this is in fact a bug.

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you posted it as a bug yet on the connect.microsoft.com page?  If not, I will post this bug there.

Comment: I actually used the same workaround for some of the problems I ran into.  Its rough to do that when you have a lot of text though.

Comment: :) nop - too lazy to write up the bug report
I must say that it's kind of a trivial bug (in the sense that i would have expected it to be wide spread and well known) and i am kind of surprised it wasn't reported or even mentioned anywhere...

Comment: Ok.  So I just got around to posting the bug on the microsoft site.  Here is the [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/659177/textblock-missing-words-at-the-end-of-a-line#details).  I would appreciate it if you would go there and indicate that you can reproduce this bug.  Hopefully my project file appears on their soon...

Comment: Also, I'm not going to mark this as the answer quite yet.  That is, until I get some sort of satisfactory response from microsoft.  I'm hoping for a better solution than what we have figured out up until now.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround this by setting TextAlignment="Left" and HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" on the TextBlock.